# How to use the same template for different query sets?

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm new to Django and setting up my first site. I have a Share model and a template called share_list.html that uses an object_list like this:

```
{% for object in object_list %}
```

I setup haystack using their tutorial and the search template looks like this:

```
{% for result in page.object_list %}
```

I would like to modify the search.html template to have an include of the share_list so I don't have to repeat myself. How can I make it use the same object_list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [`with`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#with) tag :)

```
{% with page.object_list as object_list %}
    {% include 'share_list.html' %}
{% endwith %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the names of the dict keys you use when you render the template.